# Nginx 1.14 and php7.2-fpm returns php as application/octet-stream to download

Tags: nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux, php-7.2

I got clean just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 WSL, here what i did with it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install composer npm
sudo apt install nginx postgresql-10
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-mysql php7.2-mbstring
sudo apt upgrade
```

There's my nginx config for project:

```
server {
    #listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /var/www/domains/laravel/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name laravel.loc;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

There's no changes in `nginx.conf` except `user user;` and

```
user = user
group = user
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

in `www.conf` of `php7.2-fpm's` `pool.d` directory.

So... i got SPA project on `Laravel 5.6` and `Vue.js` that worked properly on `Nginx 1.10` and `php7.0-fpm`, that returns me page on `/` and work with Vue routes as well, but if i'm trying to get `/login` or some api route (or any another url) from browser it gives me `application/octet-stream` of `public/index.php` to download. I've tried to add php mime type to nginx configs and change `default_type application/octet-stream;` in `nginx.conf` to `default_type text/html;` as i read in some advices, but it did'n do the trick. Already breaked my mind, anybody please help!

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Nope, still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to the HTTP/2 support of this version of Nginx.

HTTP/2 should always be used over SSL.

Handling HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 over SSL/ClearTCP transparently is actually really hard and not well handled by Nginx.

Try to remove any site using http2 from your Nginx enabled sites an restart Nginx.
You can also try to make your request in HTTPS, your pages should be served without any problem.

Move to HTTP/2 over SSL only or forget about HTTP/2 for the moment.